# Correctly format ASP.NET MVC dates for AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I am using AngularJS to get data from an ASP.NET server application and display it on the client side. Here is what I'm getting:

```
ProjectID │ CreatedOn
══════════╪══════════════════════
13241     │ /Date(1338364250000)/   
13411     │ /Date(1338370907000)/
```

As you can see, the date is not being displayed correctly. I want to format the date as `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`. How can I do this?

---

The HTML view:

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="FirstCtrl">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    ProjectID
                </td>
                <td>
                    CreatedOn
                </td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="team in teams" class="thumbnail">
                <td>
                    {{team.ProjectID}}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{team.CreatedOn}}
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

The action method:

```cs
public JsonResult GetUser()
{
   return Json(new { data = ProjectService.GetPrefixUsedCount(1).ToArray() });
}
```

The JSON result returned:

```
{"data":[{"ProjectID":13241,"CreatedOn":"\/Date(1338364250000)\/"},
{"ProjectID":13411,"CreatedOn":"\/Date(1338370907000)\/"}]
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### The quick fix

If changing the format in MVC isn't an option, you can do this:

```
{{ team.CreatedOn.slice(6, -2) | date: 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss' }}
```

The key bit is `.slice(6, -2)`—it trims off all the extra junk leaving you with just the epoch time.

---

### Want a filter?

If you use this a lot, you may prefer a custom filter. This one wraps [the existing `date` filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date):

```
.filter('mvcDate', ['$filter', $filter =>
  (date, format, timezone) =>
    date && $filter('date')(date.slice(6, -2), format, timezone)
]);
```

Now just replace the `date` filter with our custom one:

```
{{ team.CreatedOn | mvcDate: 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss' }}
```

Here's a [working example on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Jordan/Lg3zesy0/).

Answer (score 4):

Create custom filter as below:

```
app.filter("dateFilter", function () {
    return function (item) {
        if (item != null) {
            return new Date(parseInt(item.substr(6)));
        }
        return "";
    };
});
```

You can then apply the filter in your HTML

```
<tr ng-repeat="team in teams" class="thumbnail">
<td>{{team.CreatedOn | dateFilter | date:"dd-MM-yyyy"}}</td>
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

You should probably have a look at

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter:date

It gives you all the necessary tools to modify and display Date in the format you want.

**EDIT :**

Could you modify your server to not send the date as Date(****) but just the **** is fine... If you send the date as Date(****), then you are left with 2 options both of which arent good.

1. TO eval the Date. NO eval.. its not good for your health.
2. Strip out the Date using a combination of regex.. Again, its possible.. but not recommended.

why send it in and strip it out? Why not just take it out of the server side itself?

Comment: i tried this {{team.CreatedOn | date:'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z'}} but still display same /Date(1338364250000)/

Comment: not sure how to strip escape character, will you please tell?

Comment: @AnilD docs define date formats, pass a valid format from server or create custom filter that parses your data to a valid date

Comment: "NO eval.. its not good for your health." I still love this comment. Truly advice for the ages!

Answer (score 1):

In your ASP.NET MVC domain model have an extra property that renders the format expected by angular.

```
 public string CreatedOnJson
         {
             get
             {
                 return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(CreatedOn, new JavaScriptDateTimeConverter()).Replace("new Date(","").Replace(")","");

             }
         }
```

That way you can the use the angular date filter do display in way you prefer:

```
 {{team.CreatedOn | date:'yyyy-MM' }}
```